# Why when I flag a post in the review queue I can't see the flag in my flagging history?

Tags: discussion, flags

Why when I review some task in the review queue and I flag some post I can't see this flags in my flagging history?

Comment: You should be able to. I did once have troubles with this in the Help and Improvement Queue where it didn't show some "very low quality" flags. Can you be more specific of when/where this happens/

Comment: I don't remember where, but yesterday I flag various post, when I go to my flagging history I don't see this flags

Comment: You cast a lot of close votes yesterday, but no flags.

Comment: Were they maybe audits? If you flag an audit it doesn't do a real flag.

Comment: @animuson I when I says yesterday is yesterday on my country I see now that for SO is today ;-)

Comment: @Dronehinge I don't think that was audit, because when I see this behavior I clic the question and I flag the answer in the original question and I see the flag in my history. Then I test in the next review and I flag in the queue review and I can't see the flag in the flagging history